# what is the best configuration for innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit?

Tags: mysql, innodb

There are 3 different configuration is available for innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Which is the best configuration for innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit?

what is the difference between this three configuration?

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`  has default value of `1` - To disk on each transaction commit. is extremely expensive. Your applications can get incredible performance boost if you change the value to `2` - To OS cache on each transaction commit. To disk every second.

With a value of 2, only an operating system crash or a power outage can erase the last second of transactions. However, InnoDB's crash recovery is not affected and thus crash recovery does work regardless of the value.